# Magento Admin login kicks me out back to the Admin login

Tags: magento, authentication, admin, quota

After I enter my username and password and click "Login" it sends me back to the Login page with NO error messages. The URL changes to include a session key and that's it. Everytime I click Login again, the session key is regenerated and I still can't log into the admin interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just encountered this problem on one of my servers (not a localhost installation). Turns out the system account was over quota, so I presume Magento was unable to create the necessary temporary files. (I noticed this when trying to create a directory on the server over ssh.)

So... maybe check to make sure the account under which Magento is running isn't over quota on your server? At the very least, it might not be a Magento problem directly.

Comment: I think it's an issue at the Webmin/Virtualmin level, haven't totally figured out the cause yet (total disk usage says 1.69 GB, though files + databse is < 300 MB, trying to figure out where the other usage is coming from).

Comment: Lots of solutions out there other than this one, but for me this was the correct approach. To improve performance I had cache and session on tmpfs mount points. After a server reboot Magento login wouldn't work. Turns out the entries in fstab were missing an "m" after the size setting. After fixing a remounting login worked.

Answer (score 2):

Clear the contents of the directory `var/cache` and try again.

If that doesn't help check the table `core_config_data` in the database for records with a `path` value of "web/secure/base_url", "web/unsecure/base_url" and "admin/url/custom". These should match the page you are trying to log into (but without "index.php/admin/" at the end)

Finally check your browser's cookie settings and that the server's PHP is able to set cookies.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem running Magento 1.5.1 on my production server. I would log in to the admin, the url would show the address for the dashboard (with the secure key), but the screen would still be the login screen.  There was no error.  This happened with FF, Safari, and Chrome.

I fixed it by manually setting two core_config_data values in the database.  They are as follows:

web/cookie/cookie_path = /

web/cookie/cookie_domain = "mydomain.com"

clear out var/cache and try to log in.  For me, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Version 1.7.0.2 I have been moving my magento store from on server to another one, and I had the same problem. Use phpamdin to edit your database on new server, search for web/cookie/cookie_domain in 'config path row', the value is probably your old domain name: yourdomain.com, change that to your new domain name OR to your new IP address (new server). If you attend to use your old domain on new server environment you will probably want to set your story ready before you switch your name servers. That was the case for me, after I added my new server IP to web/cookie/cookie_domain  instead of domain I was finally able to log into my magento backend.

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems when on a local server. It was on http://server/username/ and so didn't have dots in it. If we changed the settings to be the IP address of the server then it was fine.

Comment: We aren't using a local server, we do have a sub-domain. We have two other servers with almost duplicate setups and they are not experiencing this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There can be several things that cause this behavior.  This is my checklist.  One of them will eventually fix it.

1. Click the "forgot password link" and then the "back" link.  This will remove any possibly misplaced params in the URL as well as make sure you're on the right server (some installations have separate admin servers)
2. Clear cookies or use an incognito window
3. Try another browser
4. Local installations: Try using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` (and update the base URL in the `core_config_data` table)
5. Clear Magento `cache`, `full_page_cache`, and `session` directories in the `magento/var/` directory (and repeat 1 and 2)
6. Truncate the `core_session` table
7. Verify your Magento has correct memory settings
8. Check Magento `system.log` and `exception.log` files and debug
9. Check PHP's error logs and debug

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this issue using Opera, while in other browsers it worked fine.

Also, make sure to set correct cookie options in:
System > Configuration > Web > Cookie Settings

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure that your system time / time zone on the server and php and magento match up.