# magento 1.6.2.0 keeps logging out

Tags: magento

I am using magento 1.6.2.0 and it keeps returning to to login screen every time I try to do an activity.
Things I have done:
My `php.ini` memory limits are set at 512Mb and my times set at 18000
checked the server time, `php.ini` time, and magento config time

- Cleard the cache from magento. no joy
- Cleared the cache and session from my plesk panel, no joy
- Cleaned firefox and chrome history and page cache, not joy
- reinstalled Mage_Core_Adminhtml, Mage_Core_Modules, Lib_Js_Mage, no joy
- I reinstalled mage JS, no joy

The only changes recently have been the magento php 5.4 patch and had to reinstall Mage_GoogleShopping becase the new one would never complete loading the page.
Every time I try to change to something in the admin menu I have to log back in.
I checked the `adminnotification_inbox` in the database and it was reset to zero.
I get no errors in firebug, firefox or chrome and my cookies are working although it says .nilandspalce.com. 
reinstalled magento.
It is like magento keeps resetting itself as my admin notifications keep coming back after delete 
I have no error reports or folder.
I have run out of ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've came across this issue before... Give this a try...

```
 system->configuration->admin -> select security tab and check session lifetime field
```

This is where you can define your time...

Also, if you use some .php extensions, some of their session encrypts can cause problems...

```
 For Ex: sjusin.session.encrypt = On (This would need to be turned to Off in some cases)
```

This you can find in the config file by the way

Also if this doesn't help you check this out about [quota](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036384/magento-admin-login-kicks-me-out-back-to-the-admin-login).